# How to store list in MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a game that has a few tables.

They are as follows

**Users**

user_id text

session_id text

last_login datetime

**Sessions**

session_id text

users text

categories text

**Categories**

category_id int

category_name text

---

My main problem is how to store the categories column in the sessions table. Each session is an instance of a game, and the categories are the categories of the game selected by the users. I figured I could just have a list of the category_ids that are in that session? I have the same problem with storing the users that are in a session.

Can someone help me with a better way of doing this please?

Thanks.

---

EDIT:

user_id will be a uuid. e.g. "bcb4a209-3d90-4fe4-b8ed-594976a7b836"

last_login is just when they logged in last so it'll be date and time

session_id will be an 8 character alphanumeric ID such as "9KAN4P2X"

as it stands, my idea for users would be a list of user_ids, such as "bcb4a209-3d90-4fe4-b8ed-594976a7b836, 5a8b0148-f02b-4372-9ff7-781546b5c62d"

category_id would be an integer, e.g. 32

category_name is just a string identifying the category, e.g. "Food"

categories would be a list of category_ids, e.g. 32, 42, 15

The problem is that I believe it's not advised to store lists like I suggested for users and categories, so I'm wondering how else I should do this.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: In proper columns, as formatted text. (Highlight and click `{}`.)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have done so

Comment: @jarlh Is that really necessary? I believe everything is extremely clear

Comment: If you do it properly you'll get better answers, faster. Take a look at [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you have a session that can be matched with more than one category, right?
Then create an additional table that stores the id of the session and the id of the category.
Then for the same session id you will store as many rows as category you have. 
Using JOIN you can then match the session detail with the categories details.

```
SESSION_CATEGORY
id    session_id    category_id
-------------------------------
1     1             1
2     1             2
3     1             3
```

This will be how the table will look like: for session 1 you will have category 1,2 and 3 assigned

Then doing something like

```
SELECT * FROM session_category 
    JOIN sessions on session_id=session.id
    JOIN category ON category_id=category.id
```

(query to be refined based on your data, just a draft to explain you the JOIN concept)

Comment: I see, that makes sense - thank you. So I should do the same thing for users as well?

Comment: probably yes. The idea is to hav tables to handle the one to many relationship

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean my sessions table is redundant and can be removed? I'm not sure what it would be storing except just a list of session_ids which can be found in session_category?